# Highlight parent nav when one child page?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, genesis

I'm working on a wordpress site in the Education Pro Genesis theme, and I'm trying to highlight the parent page in the main nav menu, when I click on a child page. The child page is not in the menu, but is in a side menu on the right. I got the right side menu to highlight the page it was on, but not the parent page in the main menu. For instance when you go to the ride options tab. That tab is highlighted. Then you click on public transit, but the "Ride Options" tab becomes **UNhighlighted**. I'm trying to get it to stay highlighted.

I tried:

```
li.current-menu-parent >a, .current-menu-item >a {
color: red !important;
}
```

But nothing changes. Any help is very appreciated.

This is the [URL](http://www.peninsularidesdraft.com/).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Thanks for providing your CSS, but can you please provide the relevant HTML as well? It's difficult to reproduce this without it. It would help if you could update your question to list all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your HTML is generated server-side, please post the **output**. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: use the php at the bottom of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603950/wordpress-highlight-the-parent-menu-item-when-child-menu-item-page-is-selected